# date comparison error in FTIndex search

Tags: full-text-search, xpages

I have a situation where the same database resides as Replica copies on several servers. The problem is that the servers do not all have the same default date format.

So server A has a date format of mm-dd-yyyy and server B has yyyy-mm-dd.

So a process that runs on server A sets a field called CompletedDate and stores a date of 06-25-2014. The document is replicated to server B.

Part of the user process is a search in a ful text index using this code snippet:

```
var dt:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime("Today");
dt.adjustDay(-30));
var dString:String = dt.getDateOnly();
var qString = "([WFSCompletedDate > " + dString + "])";
var dc:NotesDocumentCollection = appDB.FTSearch(qString);
```

if the client access the DB on Server A the value for dString is todays date - 30 days = 06-19-2014 and the search is successful. if accessed on server B then the dString is 2014-06-19 and not only does the FTSearch not return anything it causes an error - HTTP JVM: com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript action expression when the FTIndex attempts to evaluate 2014-06-19 to the document date of 07-19-2014.

I am not in a position to enforce all replica servers have the same default date format, and I could have a mix of dates in documents in the db as they could be created on any server. The normal date formating seems to take care of these differences, but the FTIndex comparison does not seem to be able to adjust for the differences in the date format. Any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: Have you copied your code correctly in the snippet above? The square brackets should only be round the field name, but in the snippet they're round the whole expression. If you're creating the DateTime object on the same server you're searching the full text index for, I would expect it to keep the same format for both.

Comment: When having full-text search errors, always try issuing the identical search manually and see whether there is in fact any format that works on that server. I like the suggestion that the field might have had a different data type in the past. It might even have a different data type in the present, if you have old documents hanging around with a string in that field. In that case you have to fix the faulty documents, or it's a matter of chance whether the field is indexed as a string or a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd also suggest checking by searching in Notes Client. The search bar helps verify the data type the full text index is expecting, as well as identifying any syntax issues. I tend to print out the search string and then use that in the Notes Client, to help double-check I haven't made a mistake.

Comment: This gets stranger and stranger - When I originally created the query I did as you suggested by using the search bar so I went back to it. In the db on server A I entered [WFSCompletedDate] >  06/21/2014 and got the result I had expected -returned one hit. In the DB on server B (which is a brand new replica) I did the same and got no hits. Tried different date formats but no difference. 
I'm not a great Domino Admin but are there any Notes.ini settings on the server that might impact this? I'm at a total loss.

Comment: Very strange. Might be worth trying deleting and recreating the index, if you haven't. If it's a problem with the UNK table though, it's not that easy, as I covered in the blog post.

Comment: Would not deleteing the database and creating a new replica create a new UNK table? Because that is what I did after assigning a specific date to each doc that contains the field WFSCompletedDate.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The UNK table is separate and basically lists all fields and data types. It's a database schema (as Nathan pointed out in an IBM Connect session a few years ago) that gets created or updated when documents are created. It's separate from the design and from the Full Text Index. To recreate it (and I had to do it on a production server a couple of years ago), you need to delete the index, do a copy-style compact, then create the index anew. See Duffbert's blog post from many years ago! http://www.duffbert.com/duffbert/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TDUF-5SMHV4

Comment: Apache Solr is being used for Mail Next and my understanding from IBM Connect 2014 was that it will eventually mean the Full Text Indexing we currently use will be deprecated. With backwards compatibility of Domino I'm sure it will still work, but Solr will be a better alternative.

Comment: Well after way to many hours of painful frustration I found that yes there were some fields that upon replication got converted to Text because they were blank in the data set on server A. Populated those fields with a meaning less date they now show as Date/time - delete index compact -c put index back on still fails. Checked every document in the DB non have the field that should not. On Server B did a New Copy of the database and build index. Search works. deleted the original Db on server B and then replicate back to server A - delete the original DB on server A. Back in production but !!!

Answer (score 0):

bill - have you tried forcing the dstring value to be the desired format by building the date only string from the date/time components of the stored value? by that I mean to pull out the month, day and year and build the date from those pieces.

Comment: The problem with that is that I don't know what the stored value format will be, and it could be different for each server. But in this case the date WFSCompletedDate is set from a scheduled LS agent so I guess I could set it to dd-mm-yyyy or a known format, then as you suggest build dString to the same sequence. This would be a bit of a pain but would probably make it work. I will have to try it out and see what happens. The comparison should be able to compare two dates of different format.

Comment: John - I formated the date in the SSJS to be dd/mm/yyyy and that works fine in the search on Server A (the one that the date WFSCompletedDate was set on and has a default date of dd/mm/yyyy. When I run exactly the same code agains the same data set on server B with default date of yyyy/mm/dd it fails with the EvaluationException error. So the comparator ([WFSCompletedDate > " + dString + "]) is crashing regardless how I format dString (mm/dd/yyyy, dd/mm/yyyy, yyyy.mm.dd) but on server A it actually works even when passing dString as either mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy. really strange. ?????

Comment: to get the date format use s.getInternational().isDateDMY() where s is a NotesSession. THere is also isDateMDY() and isDateYMD()

Comment: borrowing some of serdar's line of thought...1) make sure both dbs on both servers are ft indexed. 2) make sure all docs with this date field are in fact date types and not string. 3) perhaps add a new date field and value to all docs and test ft search using that new field to see if this is a field problem or not. 4) as serdar commented, and i think have done, only use brackets around the date field name. 5) as serdar did, use java.util.Date type so you easily extract date components to build date string. (dt.getMonth()+1)+"/"+dt.getDay()+"/"+dt.getFullYear()

Comment: I think the issue is that the field WFSCompletedDate is blank to begin with then set later on. I'm going to set it on creation of the document to some date in the long passed (  I use "1970/01/01 0:0:0 AM GMT" as a 'blank' date) then see what happens. The od thing is that the search works on one server but not on the other. The databases are both FTIndexed.

Comment: On checking the datatype of the field WFSCompletedDate on server B they were in fact converted to text. So created an agent on Server A that populated the blank date field with the date  "1970/01/01 0:0:0 AM GMT" and set the field to the Local Time. checked them all and they are properly assigned as Date/Time. Replicated to server B, deleted the FTIndex and rebuilt it ran the appDb.FTSearch(qString) and I get the same EvaluationException error. Checked the fields on server B and they are Date/Time. Not sure what the next step should be.

Comment: After the above failed I deleted the DB on Server B (fortunately they are still small and in test mode) then created a new replica from the DB on Server A. So any hangover from the change in datatypes should be gone, but my FTSearch works on Server A but fails with the EvaluationException on server B. If I remove the reference to the field WFSCompletedDate in my qString but keep the rest of the query it works well on both servers. It is very curious!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know FT search syntax is locale-agnostic. It always accepts "month/date/year" format as long as the field has date/time value. Data time values are also stored as locale-agnostic.

I also see you have used `[FIELDNAME > VALUE]` format. I'm surprised it works for the other server because correct format should be `[FIELDNAME] > VALUE` ([here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTWP_8.5.2/com.ibm.notes85.help.doc/sch_refine_query_r.html?lang=en))

The problem is probably about `dString` in the code. Try as following:

```
var dt:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime("Today");
dt.adjustDay(-30);
var jdt:java.util.Date=dt.toJavaDate();
var formatter=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

var dString = formatter.format(jdt);
var qString = "([WFSCompletedDate] > " + dString)";

var dc:NotesDocumentCollection = appDB.FTSearch(qString);
```

Comment: Serdar - made the changes that you suggested. Works fine of the server that created the document (always has) but still get the EvaluationException. My guess is that there is something else different between the two servers that is causing the problem, but no idea what. Will keep poking and see if I can figure it out. definitely related to the date evaaluation because my qString is a whole lot more complex but if I remove the date comparison it works the same on both servers.

Comment: Check for one more issue. There is a known problem with UNK tables (which is different for each replica). If the field was text before and converted to Date/Time later, FTSearch problems can be seen. To check that, try with a different date/time field. Read it from Paul Withers: http://www.intec.co.uk/full-text-search-musings/

Comment: That is probably it. The field is created as a date/time on server A but is left blank, when it replicates the blank field appears to revert to text. See my comment below - will set date to "1970/01/01 0:0:0 AM GMT" on creation. Will do that tomorrow and post the results here.